# Angular2: style md-radio-button and md-checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-mdl

I've an angular2 app, with an  md-radio-button and md-checkbox components, but i'm not able to change styles of this component. I've try different modes, but whithout success. Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you are missing something, can you show us the relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

After `md-checkbox` or any ui component is rendered it'll look like something as given below. you can add `class` to main component and pick the child html tags directly and style them up. this is `mdl-checkbox` from `angular2-mdl`

#### mdl-checkbox

```html
<mdl-checkbox class="mycheckbox mdl-checkbox is-upgraded ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
 <input class="mdl-checkbox__input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox">
 <span class="mdl-checkbox__label"> General </span>
 <span class="mdl-checkbox__focus-helper"></span>
 <span class="mdl-checkbox__box-outline">
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__tick-outline"></span>
 </span>
</mdl-checkbox>
```

#### My custom css

```css
.mycheckbox .mdl-checkbox__input{
 background-color: #f00;
}
```